# SQL Join Everything From One Table With One Feild From Another Table?

Tags: sql, join

Is there a way to specify a join on all fields from table A with only one field from table B?

Is it necessary to specify each individual field from each table instead of using the all symbol (*) for one of the tables?

Comment: Sounds like you want a cross join, but it would be best to see an example of the data you're dealing with along and the output you expect.  Knowing what database you're using would help us to be able to help you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to:

```
select tableA.*, tableB.someField
```